# if item *in* array java

Tags: java, python, arrays

I'm a python programmer who is learning java

I ran across the following *problem* (or maybe complication is a better term to use)

In python, I can easily check if an item is in a list within an if statement like so:

```py
x = 1
if x in [0,1,2,3,4,5]:
    #do something
```

#### what is the easiest way to do that in java?

- can I do it without using a list variable like in the example above?

e.g

```
{0,1}.contains(1)
```

> (not sure if this is a duplicate, I did look, if it is be sure to flag it for =)

Comment: The usual way is `if (array.contains(item))`

Comment: i belive i tried that, and {0,1}.contains(1) didn't work; im going for simplicity

Comment: @JohnGordon java array primitives don't have `contains` method

Comment: I don't think you can call methods on Java literals directly. In any case, in *both* Python and Java, what you are doing isn't a great practice. You should be using some variable, e.g. `haystack = [0, 1, 2, ,3, 4, 5]` and then `if x in hastack: ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would it not be practical if its something small like `if answer.lower() in [1,"yes", "y"]`? i know i can use `if (answer == "1" | answer == "yes" | ...)` in java but that's doesn't feel too clean

Comment: @Ironkey using constants like that in expressions just leads to less maintainable code. You *can* do it, but it's a bad habit. In any case, in Java, I'd probably just use the boolean expression instead of the transliteration of whatever Python you'd do.

Comment: `i know i can use if (answer == "1" | answer == "yes" | ...) in java` - NO, this is not how you compare Strings in java.

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, very good catch.

Comment: @ScaryWombat well in my specific case it was `(answer == 0 | answer == 1)`

Comment: @Ironkey arrays are really low level java constructs that you shouldn't ever use unless you really know you need that. Imagine python has low level access to glibc `free` and `malloc`, to let you allocate and free large contiguous blocks of memory. You COULD use those to write a basic intlist, but even a simple `contains` is quite hard and not object oriented in the slightest. Java's arrays are just like that. The java equivalent of a python array is `java.util.ArrayList`, not arrays.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thank you that's a very good explanation for me; ill be sure to start using ArrayList then!

Comment: @rzwitserloot a Python *list* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(array).contains("---something---"))
```

Comment: `int[] nums = {0, 1, 123}; System.out.println(Arrays.asList(nums).contains(0));` returns `false`; now i do like this implementation, but it does need a variable to reference to the array (or list)

Comment: @Ironkey yeah, that won't work because you can't have a list of primitive types, so it's actually creating a list of `int []` objects, so a list of size 1. You *can* use `Integer[] nums = {0, 1, 123}` but in modern java you'd just create the list directly, `List<Integer> nums = List.of(0, 1, 123);` Basically, don't expect to be able to do a lot of the stuff you could in Python in Java. Java is *much more verbose*. Also, you almost always want to use a `List` of some kind instead of a primitive array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga exactly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok i see; one *last* thing: `Integer[] x = {0, 1, 123}; List<Integer> y = List.of(0, 1, 123);` with `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(x).contains(1)); System.out.println(Arrays.asList(y).contains(1));`

returns `true` `false`

is it taking the second as a primitive type as well?

Comment: @Ironkey No, `List` is not a primitive. But it is creating a `List<List<Integer>>` because `Arrays.asList` either takes an *array* or a variable number of arguments, e.g. `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so what would the fix be for that?

Comment: @Ironkey the fix is to stop using `Arrays.asList(x)`... *why are you doing that*? Just use `y.contains(1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh oh, alright sorry, I see lol; thanks a lot, I understand this a lot more now!

Answer (score 3):

Another method may help you.

**If the array element is consecutive sequenceuse:**

```
int x = 1;
if (IntStream.range(0, 6).anyMatch(value -> value == x)) {
    // do something like print message
    System.out.println("find x");
}
```

**If the element of array is non-contiguous sequence:**

```
int x = 1;
int[] inputs = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10};
if (Arrays.stream(inputs).anyMatch(value -> value == x)) {
    // do something like print message
    System.out.println("find x");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use arrays, that means once u create a arrays u cant change his size, Then I parse the arrays with a for loop and check if my values `x` is equals to my values in `myArrays` in the iteration `i` of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 2;
        int [] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if(x == myArray[i])
            {
                //do something
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: i do know how to implement that i was just wondering if there was a way to directly reference an array (like in py)

Comment: @Ironkey In java we can't directly reference an array like python